# Passing results to a -like filter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filter, output

I am trying to create a script to take care of a repetitive task I have.  Basically I need to get the person's ID that manages a particular folder.
My first script tells me the various security groups assigned to a specified folder.  The second script takes a specified AD group and tells me who manages it.  Ideally I want to just run the script, input my folder name and have it tell me who manages the various AD groups assigned.  I can then go and do the rest.  But I am having an issue with the output of the first script.  I have it so it displays in the console correctly, but I cannot figure out how to get those results into the filter in the second script.

Script one:

```bsh
$FN = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter Folder name"
$ADG = (Get-Acl $FN).Access |
       Select IdentityReference |
       Where-Object IdentityReference -like '*SL*'
foreach ($ACL in $ADG) {
    $Group.Fullname + ($ACL.IdentityReference.Value.Split('\'))[1] | Out-String
}
```

Script two:

```bsh
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "use output here"} -Properties managedby |
    Select managedby
```

I would be most appreciative of any assistance.  ESPECIALLY if I am barking up the wrong PowerShell command!  My first foray into using multiple queries in a script.

Comment: typically, one simply puts both bits of code in the same script - thus allowing one to pas a $Var from the 1st part to the 2nd. [*grin*]  ///// as an aside, where is `$Group` coming from in your 1st script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what the `$Group.Fullname + (...)[1] | Out-String` is supposed to do, but assuming that you want to run the second command for each identity reference from your first command you could do something like this:

```cs
Get-Acl $FN |
    Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object -Expand IdentityReference |
    Where-Object { $_.Value -like '*SL*' } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_.Value.Split('\', 2)[-1]
        Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*${name}*'" -Property ManagedBy
    } |
    Select-Object -Expand ManagedBy |
    Get-ADUser
```

Comment: The $Group.Fullname +...... was striping off the domain part of the ACL so I could have just the Group name itself to pass thru to the command.    This has me almost there, now I just need to see if I can get it to show the group they are managing.  I am definitely going to compare your script to mine to see what does what to get a better understanding.  Thanks!

Comment: @S.Raines You can put the trailing `Select-Object | Get-ADUser` directly after the `Get-ADGroup` and then output a custom object with both group name (`$name`) and its manager.

Comment: Got the script giving me the information the way I need it.  Thanks again Ansgar!